# F# force an overload of System.String.Format

Tags: f#, overloading

I would like to format a string using `System.String.Format` which has 5 overloads:

```
String String.Format(String format , Object arg0 )
String String.Format(String format , Object arg0 , Object arg1 )
String String.Format(String format , Object arg0 , Object arg1 , Object arg2 )
String String.Format(String format , params Object[] args )
String String.Format(IFormatProvider provider , String format , params Object[] args )
```

I would like to use the fourth overload (the one that takes an array of objects) like this:

```
let frm = "{0} - {1}"
let args = [| 1; 2 |]
System.String.Format(frm, args)
```

The problem is that the args argument is interpreted as an Object and hence the first overload is called. So correctly I get the following error:

```
System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

Is there a way to force the "correct" overload?

Comment: yes ... so I should just cast all elements into object?

Comment: Any reason for not doing the idiomatic: `sprintf "%d - %d" 1 2` - it's there exactly to avoid this problem? Any reason why you want to create a redundant array instead of calling the second overload via `String.Format( "{0} - {1}", box 1, box 2)` ? Or why not `sprintf "%A" [| 1; 2 |]` ? (I'm sure you have a reason but no harm to be clear why these avenues are inappropriate to enable the best possible answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A more elegant variant of @John's answer is to add type annotation so that the compiler will do automatic upcast on all elements of an array:

```
let frm = "{0} - {1}"
let args : obj [] = [| 1; 2 |]
System.String.Format(frm, args)
```

Comment: I just had to do this last night!

Answer (score 2):

You can force the correct overload by switching each element of the array to an object like so:

```
let frm = "{0} - {1}"
let args = [| 1:> obj; 2 :>obj|]
System.String.Format(frm, args);;
```

or if you have a longer list

```
let frm = "{0} - {1}"
let args = [| 1; 2 |] |> Array.map (fun t ->t:> obj)
System.String.Format(frm, args);;
```

Comment: @JohnPalmer, you can also do `Array.map box`, which should do the same thing.